# How do I return a list inside a for loop while iterating over the elements of another list?

Tags: python

I have two lists. The first list contains :
L1 = [a,b]
The second list contains :
L2 = []
I need to iterate over the values of these two lists in nested for loops. What I mean by that is :

```
for elems1 in L1:
   ---some-actions---
   for val in value:
      result = val1,val2,val3
      L2.append(result)
      print(L2)

   #additional tasks 
   for vals in L2:
        ---additional-tasks to be performed---
```

When I print(L2), I get something like this :

```
['val1']
['val1','val2'] 
['val1','val2','val3']
```

Why is it printing thrice and listing each value separately ? Ideally the output should be

```
['val1','val2','val3']
```

Comment: _"Why is it printing thrice"_ Because your `print` is inside a loop?

Comment: You told it to `print` every time through the loop, just after appending each element.  This is an excellent debugging tool.  For what you want, though, just pull the `print` outside the loop: reduce the indentation by one level (shift it left).

Comment: Yeah got it .. Thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

Your print() is inside the loop so it gets called multiple times.
Put it outside the loop like this:

```
for val in value:
      result = val1,val2,val3
      L2.append(result)
print(L2)
```